# How to build a PropertyGroup entry from an ItemGroup in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

I'm very new to MSBuild and am having trouble figuring out how to construct a PropertyGroup entry from conditional parts.

Here's what I have, which is not working:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CompilerDirective Include="DEBUG_PARANOID" Condition=" '$(SomeFlag)' == 'true' "/>
    <CompilerDirective Include="DEBUG"/>
    <CompilerDirective Include="TRACE"/>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <DefineConstants>@(CompilerDirective)</DefineConstants>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'd like the constants that get defined to show up as DEBUG_PARANOID;DEBUG;TRACE if SomeFlag is set true, leaving out DEBUG_PARANOID if not. This is for a .csproj, by the way.

If I print out @(CompilerDirective) with a message task, it works.

My question is how to make this work inside of a PropertyGroup entry?

Comment: Btw: That is bad form to construct properties from ItemGroups. Just construct a property from other properties. It's much easier that way.

Comment: ItemGroups are meant to point to FILES, not arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have above works.  I ran this:

```
<Target Name="Test">
  <ItemGroup>
      <CompilerDirective Include="DEBUG_PARANOID"
        Condition=" '$(SomeFlag)' == 'true' "/>
      <CompilerDirective Include="DEBUG"/>
      <CompilerDirective Include="TRACE"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>@(CompilerDirective)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="$(DefineConstants)" />
</Target>
```

and got the proper output
    DEBUG;TRACE
or
    DEBUG_PARANOID;DEBUG;TRACE
depending on the value of the property.  In what manner does this not work for you?

Comment: Well, how about that.. Ok, the reason I thought it wasn't working is that when I'd look at build properties in VS, they'd come in as @(CompilerDirective), rather than the expanded list. I had assumed it would expand it because it also expands `USER_$(USERNAME.ToUpper())` (which I left out to reduce noise in my example). Well thank you!